# Set display orientation failed in android camera

Tags: android, android-camera

I published a week ago an app named "Cam Shooter" which uses a camera surfaceview and a fire button.I got more than 20 reports about this error:

```
 java.lang.RuntimeException: set display orientation failed
 at android.hardware.Camera.setDisplayOrientation(Native Method)
 at com.jouni.camsniper.MainActivity.surfaceChanged(MainActivity.java:139)
 at android.view.SurfaceView.updateWindow(SurfaceView.java:573)
 at android.view.SurfaceView.setFrame(SurfaceView.java:296)
 at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7199)
 at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:912)
 at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7205)
 at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:912)
 at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7205)
 at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:338)
 at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7205)
 at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:338)
 at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7205)
 at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:1145)
 at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1870)
 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:875)
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:633)
 at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

In my code there is some lines to fix the rotation and aspect ratio of the camera, maybe it is causing the problem.

```
 @Override
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {       
    Parameters parameters = mCamera.getParameters();
    List<Camera.Size> previewSizes = parameters.getSupportedPreviewSizes();
    Camera.Size previewSize = previewSizes.get(4); //480h x 720w

    parameters.setPreviewSize(previewSize.width, previewSize.height);
    parameters.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_AUTO);
    parameters.setFocusMode(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_AUTO);

    mCamera.setParameters(parameters);

    Display display = ((WindowManager)getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay();
    if(display.getRotation() == Surface.ROTATION_0) {                        
        mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(90);                             // LINE 139
    } else if(display.getRotation() == Surface.ROTATION_270) {
        mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(180);
    }

    mCamera.startPreview();
}
```

Does anyone know how to get rid of this error ?

Comment: at com.jouni.camsniper.MainActivity.surfaceChanged(MainActivity.java:139)   <--- show this line plz

Comment: I added the code look at line 139 I marked it with a note

Comment: my android-book recommends to use as the first line of the surfacechanged()-method: if (mCamera == null) return; //but i doubt that has anything to do with your problem here :)

Answer (score 1):

Have you found a solution to your issue?  I'm wondering whether you've tried to stop capturing and drawing preview frames before setting new rotation of preview display?  For example:

```
mCamera.stopPreview();                    
mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(degrees);
mCamera.startPreview();
```